# jquery toggle text for seperate div's

Tags: jquery

I have the code that toggles text for individual panels when I click on it, but I need the text to also toggle when clicked on a different panel. Here's the code:

```
$(".subpaneltext").click(function() {
  if ($(this).closest('.mainpanel').find('.morequestions').hasClass("togglequestions")) {
$(this).closest('.mainpanel').find('.morequestions').removeClass("togglequestions");
} else {
$('.morequestions').removeClass("togglequestions");
$(this).closest('.mainpanel').find('.morequestions').addClass("togglequestions");
}
$(this).text(function(i, text) {
return text === "See more questions..." ? "See less questions..." : "See more questions...";
 })
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the HTML as well and create a fiddle or plunker for this?

Comment: Do you also have the html code? e.g. make a https://jsfiddle.net/ so show it

Comment: @Vandesh https://jsfiddle.net/rksa2f3g/1/

Comment: So you need the one you click on to toggle, and if you click on another one, the first one needs to close?

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup When I click on another one, I need the first one to close, which it does, but it also needs to change text from 'See more' to 'See less', which I can't figure out. At the moment code only toggles text for the one I click on.

Comment: @Vandesh I have updated jsfiddle to better reflect by problem. Hope it helps. https://jsfiddle.net/rksa2f3g/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rksa2f3g/7/) for what you want.

There's a lot of scope for refactoring, but as a quick solution, apart from changing the current text with this code -

```
$(this).text(function(i, text) {
return text === "See more questions..." ? "See less questions..." : "See more questions...";
 })
```

I also added, this piece of code -

```
$(".subpaneltext").not($(this)).text(function(i, text) {
    if(text === "See less questions..."){
      return "See more questions...";
    }
    return text;
  });
```

which, according to your logic of checking texts, will check for everything else, but `.not`([check the docs](http://api.jquery.com/not/)) the current one (`this`) and change only the texts which are expanded. Again, this can be refactored on so many levels!

Comment: Thank you so much @Vandesh, it works great. Sorry for this question, but what exactly should I consider doing when you say there's a lot of scope for refactoring.? I'm learning jquery bit by bit and making lots of mistakes, but any useful information is all that I need moving forward to improve. Thanks again.!

Comment: You could post that on codereview.stackexchange.com to get inputs on refactoring. General idea would be to avoid repetitive code, iterate on DOM elements as less as possible. narrowing down the conditions etc.
For now, if what I suggested works, please accept the answer.